# Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsdl, pojo

I'm getting this error while trying to generate Java POJO classes from the WSDL via intelliJ. Please help me fix this.

Comment: you can use wsimport tool.

Comment: Try using Java 8, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197921.